# Java Military Time Program Not Working

Tags: java, time

My program is not working, and the errors only show up after I run the program. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
public class Time {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public void setTime(int h, int m, int s)
    {
        hour = ((h>=0 && h<24) ? h : 0);
        minute = ((m>=0 && m<60) ? m : 0);
        second= ((s>=0 && s<60) ? s : 0);
    }

    public String toMilitary()
    {
        return String.format("%02d:","%02d:", "%02d:", hour, minute, second);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    }    
}

public class Time2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time TimeObject= new Time();
        System.out.println(TimeObject.toMilitary());
        TimeObject.setTime(13,27,6);
        System.out.println(TimeObject.toMilitary());    
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? You shouldn't need 2 main functions...

Comment: @OscuroAA Ok, thanks I will combine it into one main function.

Comment: consider using `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ok thank you for the advice

Answer (score 3):

```
String.format("%02d:","%02d:", "%02d:", hour, minute, second);
```

This is wrong. It should be:

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
```

`String.format` takes *one* format string and *any amount* of objects to format into that string. What you have is three format strings and three objects to format into it.

But you should probably try out [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as Scary Wombat suggested.

Comment: Now I see what I did wrong. Thank you so much.